# Syntax highlighting for comments in text mode

Tags: font-lock

From time to time I open a script or config file for which there is no major mode defined. When I invoke `comment-region` within that buffer, Emacs will prompt me for the comment syntax, and save it as the buffer-local variable `comment-start`.

**Can I enable syntax highlighting of comment lines in that buffer?**

Once the variable `comment-start` has been set, what other steps do I need to take in order for `font-lock-mode` to start highlighting my comment lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works for me:

```
(setq comment-start "#")
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("#.+" . font-lock-comment-face)))
```

**Edit**

Here's a more general solution:

```
(defun set-comment-char (char)
  "Sets comment char for current buffer."
  (interactive "sComment char: ")
  (setq comment-start char)
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil `((,(concat comment-start ".+") . font-lock-comment-face)))
  )
```

**Edit 2**:

Here's a more general solution:

```
(define-derived-mode text-mode-with-hash-comments text-mode
  "text-mode with # comments"

  (setq comment-start "#")
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("#.+" . font-lock-comment-face)))
)
```

Comment: I agree that it works, but it is also not very generalized.